# Not able to get write permission on android device running lollipop and pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am giving READ and WRITE permission in Manifest. Here is code from manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Here is image link showing app permission from settings 
    https://ibb.co/dJvW8ZF

I am not able to write data to my external/internal storage.

Comment: Could you please add the error log and the actual code that performs write operation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for permission before you have the need to write data.

You will need to do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 1;

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
         // write data
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission();
  }

  private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
       // write data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Explicit permissions are only needed for devices on Android M and above.

Comment: Yup it's clearly visible in the code i shared

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

Comment: Yeah, but did you notice that the question is for android devices running lollipop and pre-lollipop.